# How can I create a nested table of contents in apiary?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

It is necessary to add sub-items to the table of contents to make it easier to navigate the existing methods, but unfortunately, I cannot find the documentation where this would be described.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOC is constructed from the header blocks of your api blueprint document. It's limited to two levels of depth.

But within resource groups the nested headers are reserved for actions. The actions aren't listed on the TOC.

Here is an example of grouping resources:
https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/examples/04-grouping-resources.html

Comment: I cannot understand why when I use nesting, nested lists are not displayed in the left menu

Comment: For example, I have 3 levels of depth:

 # Group Messages


## My Message [/message]

### Retrieve a Message [GET]         Level 3 is not displayed as sub-item 2

Comment: It's like that by design. If all the Actions would be visible on the TOC it would get really cluttered in big documents. Just to be sure, in your example the Level 3 is an Action.

Comment: But why for example in this documentation API list have sub-item? https://apiary.docs.apiary.io/#reference/api-list

Comment: The sub-items you see on this document are equivalent of what you have in yours as `Some Route` and `Some Route 2`. They are Transactions and not Actions. The actions in this document are `Get User API List`, `Get Team API List`, that are also not present on the TOC.

Comment: Now I realized that sub-items can only be at the 1st nesting level. Thank you!